# ¿Como agregar un logo en el Sidemenu de Ionic?

Tags: ionic

Quiero agregar un logo en el sidemenu pero no se ajusta, supongo que deberia ser en el archivo css con un div obviamente. Así se encuentra hasta ahora:

[image: Logo]

Codigo:

```html
<ion-side-menus>
<ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-balanced">
      <img src="notilogia.jpg" width="50" height="50"/>
    </ion-header-bar>
    
    <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
         <a class="item item-icon-left" ui-sref="app.inicio" menu-close><i class="icon ion-home"></i> Inicio</a>
     <a class="item item-icon-left" ui-sref="app.notigestion" menu-close><i class="icon ion-clipboard"></i> Notigestión</a>
     <a class="item item-icon-left" ui-sref="app.politica" menu-close><i class="icon ion-person-stalker"></i> Política</a>
     <a class="item item-icon-left" ui-sref="app.deporte" menu-close><i class="icon ion-ios-football"></i> Deporte</a>
     <a class="item item-icon-left" ui-sref="app.tendencia" menu-close><i class="icon ion-bowtie"></i> Tendencia</a>
     <a class="item item-icon-left" ui-sref="app.gastronomia" menu-close><i class="icon ion-fork"></i> Gastronomía</a>
     <a class="item item-icon-left" ui-sref="app.amazon" menu-close><i class="icon ion-ipad"></i> Amazon</a>
     <a class="item item-icon-left" ui-sref="app.salud" menu-close><i class="icon ion-ios-pulse"></i> Salud</a>
    <a class="item item-icon-left" ui-sref="app.acerca" menu-close><i class="icon ion-help-circled"></i>Acerca</a>
    </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-side-menu>

    <!--contenido-->
    <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-balanced">
        <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
        <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
        </ion-nav-bar>
    
        <!--insertar contenido-->
        <ion-nav-view name="content"></ion-nav-view>
        
    </ion-side-menu-content>

</ion-side-menus>
```

Quiero ajustarlo al menu pero sobretodo, que la imagen tenga un poco más de largo. (Cabe destacar que mi archivo css no posee absolutamente nada)

Answer (score 1):

El problema está aquí:

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-balanced">
  <img src="notilogia.jpg" width="50" height="50"/>
</ion-header-bar>
```

Ahora mismo estás haciendo que la imagen que hace de logo sea cuadrada y tenga un tamaño de 50x50 pixels. Un tamaño que excede el tamaño de la cabecera (con los padding).

La solución sería o bien ampliar el alto de `ion-header-bar` (aunque no sé si eso es lo que quieres porque el icono seguiría siendo cuadrado); o bien cambiar los valores de `width` y `height` en la imagen que hace de icono para que se ajuste mejor a lo que quieres y al tamaño de la barra del menú (por ejemplo, prueba a poner `<img src="notilogia.jpg" width="60" height="35"/>` o algún valor que sea proporcional as aspecto de la imagen que usas).

Comment: De hecho quiero ampliar el ion-header-bar y es parte de la pregunta, intente ampliar fue la imagen con el width y height como lo describes, pero no se ajusta al header completamente, quedan bordes.

Comment: @JuanMotta trataste de quitar los bordes.